# What to call it when someone always looks for greener pastures?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary, expressions

Someone who always looks for the "better" and more ideal places (to live), jobs, things to buy that fit his taste/mood etc. He is always looking for better because he always feels it's "not enough".

Comment: Looking for " better " things always and looking for things that fit your taste/mood are 2 different things.

Comment: "Looking for better things to fit your taste/mood" was the meaning of that sentence. Not just looking for things that fit your taste/mood.

Answer (score 5):

Although Maulik V. is right in stating that what you describe is human behaviour, not all humans display the behaviour in such a way that it deserves special attention. For the cases where the behaviour is note-worthy (and potentially annoying), you could use **opportunist**: it describes someone who will see and seize any opportunity to advance their own position. As an adjective, you can describe the person as *opportunistic*.

As for the neutral description of the behaviour, as you mentioned in the question already, that person is *looking for greener pastures*. An expression that also fits is **the grass is always greener on the other side of the fence**, which describes the tendency that humans display to always assume life is better somewhere else (in a literal or figurative way).

Comment: opportunist may also imply lack of ethics or moral integrity when it comes to accomplishing a goal. Opportunists often times exploit the situation. I don't know the answer, but I am eager to know if there is such a term implying " seeking out better opportunities" yet not implying " exploiting or being smart in using the presented opportunity" but just plain "looking for better things/opportunities".

Comment: @NANDAGOPAL I agree on the negative connotations, which is why I said it would work for someone displaying the mentioned behaviour excessively :) For the neutral version, the OP answered it in the question: someone is looking for greener pastures. I made a small _neutral_ addition :)

Answer (score 3):

This is basically a person who always feels "not enough". This is exactly the opposite of *a contented person*, someone who is content with his or her life. So, I'd like to suggest this for such a person: *a discontented person*.

***A [discontented](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/discontente) person*** is someone who feels unhappy with his or her life. This might be a result of several possible reasons, such as they feel like they are prevented from achieving something (they're ***[frustrated](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/frustrated)***), they might feel that they're treated unfairly (they're ***[resentful](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/resentful)***), or they might just simply want more (they're ***[insatiable](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/insatiable)***).

<sub>A few words with a similar meaning to *insatiable* are ***greedy***, ***voracious***, and ***esurient***.</sub>

---

As an aside, I googled for these words to see if anything interesting might come up, and I found this interesting essay:

> *"In subservience to the internal demands of this system* [modern commercial culture], *the elementary need for material sustenance, for the basic requisites of life, becomes blown up into an insatiable urge for status, power, and luxury. The masters of commerce strive to create in us a perpetual discontent, to induce feelings of inadequacy, to stir up the need to purchase more. As a result, envy and resentment replace contentment; titillation replaces satisfaction; prestige value eclipses life value. The one word to be banished from the dictionaries is “enough.” For the corporate-based economy to flourish there must never be enough, but always a thirst for more: for the bigger, faster, and better; for novelty and variety."*
>   –– [Facing the Future: Four Essays on the Social Relevance of Buddhism](http://www.bps.lk/olib/wh/wh438.pdf), by Bhikkhu Bodhi

Answer (score 1):

A "restless" person might always be "looking for greener pastures", or think "the grass is greener on the other side of the fence".